# How to merge one property of a subset collection to the collection in the mongo without reading the data out of the database

Tags: mongodb, merge

I have two collections in the mongo, **grid_metro**, and **grid**. Here is the schema for the two collections. The only difference between the two collections is the "properties". **grid_metro** is the subset of the **grid** except for the "properties". I want to delete the **grid_metro** and merge "the properties" of **grid_metro** to that of **grid**. For the following example, I want to merge the properties.dist of **grid_metro** to properties of **grid**. The **FinalGrid** is the result.
In the **grid_metro** collection,

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a0f1264935ade4228003dd2"),
"geometry" : {
    "coordinates" : [
        [
            [
                -115.40485382080078,
                48.99981679184217
            ],
            [
                -115.40451049804688,
                48.99981679184217
            ],
            [
                -115.40451049804688,
                49.000042032153935
            ],
            [
                -115.40485382080078,
                49.000042032153935
            ],
            [
                -115.40485382080078,
                48.99981679184217
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "type" : "Polygon"
},
"properties" : {
    "center" : [
        -115.40468215942383,
        48.99992941199805
    ],
    "dist" : 19983.687678318234,
    "tile" : [
        188147,
        360104
    ]
},
"type" : "Feature"
```

}

In the collection **grid**,

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a0f1264935ade4228003dd2"),
"geometry" : {
    "coordinates" : [
        [
            [
                -115.40485382080078,
                48.99981679184217
            ],
            [
                -115.40451049804688,
                48.99981679184217
            ],
            [
                -115.40451049804688,
                49.000042032153935
            ],
            [
                -115.40485382080078,
                49.000042032153935
            ],
            [
                -115.40485382080078,
                48.99981679184217
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "type" : "Polygon"
},
"properties" : {
    "center" : [
        -115.40468215942383,
        48.99992941199805
    ],
    "roadDist" : 1124.24,
    "tile" : [
        188147,
        360104
    ]
},
"type" : "Feature"
```

}
The result what I want is **FinalResult** collection,

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a0f1264935ade4228003dd2"),
"geometry" : {
    "coordinates" : [
        [
            [
                -115.40485382080078,
                48.99981679184217
            ],
            [
                -115.40451049804688,
                48.99981679184217
            ],
            [
                -115.40451049804688,
                49.000042032153935
            ],
            [
                -115.40485382080078,
                49.000042032153935
            ],
            [
                -115.40485382080078,
                48.99981679184217
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "type" : "Polygon"
},
"properties" : {
    "center" : [
        -115.40468215942383,
        48.99992941199805
    ],
    "dist" : 19983.687678318234,
    "roadDist": 1124.24,
    "tile" : [
        188147,
        360104
    ]
},
"type" : "Feature"
```

}

There is one solution: get the properties.dist from **grid_metro** and put it to the corresponding properties of **grid**. But the method is too slow. Getting data from the mongo doesn't take much time while reading data takes. So I would like to merge the collection in the mongo without reading the data from the mongo to merge. 
The second solution: using $lookup. But it could just copy the whole object of **grid_metro** to "properties“ of **grid**.
If someone has some good idea, please let me know. Thank you very much!!!!!!

Comment: There is a useful link about merge object in the mongo.https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/#exp._S_mergeObjects

Comment: MapReduce is slow and not suitable for the big data processing.